# R package for visualizing and exploring large datasets

Tags: r, data-visualization, exploratory-data-analysis

I recently read about a package, which I believe had a name like "tabstat" or "tablestats" which produced a really useful plot of univariate distributions of multiple variables for large datasets.  I believe this package was developed by google, but am not sure.  I can't seem to find it anywhere (tabstat on google returns a lot of results).

If I'm completely crazy, and this package doesn't exist, what are some good packages for explore really huge datasets?  I know plyr has some methods for binning 2D scatterplots to reduce overplotting, but I don't know of any other good packages for visually summarize huge datasets.

Comment: also try bigvis package from hadley [http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/bigvis.pdf](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/bigvis.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of approaches and packages to solve this type of question, here is one particular approach that may be effective: http://bridgewater.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/91/

You can also find a broader set of distribution presentation options here http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html

Answer (score 2):

The package I was looking for was [tabplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tabplot/index.html)

[image: diamonds]

Comment: Note to self: this is distinct from the similarly-named package 'tableplot'

Comment: @digitgopher I've been confused by that one too.   It doesn't help that the main function of tabplot is "tableplot..."